# Sharing variables across submodules and classes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build a simple little template parser for self-learning purposes.

How do I build something "modular" and share data across it? The data doesn't need to be accessible from outside, it's just internal data. Here's what I have:

```
# template_parser.rb
module TemplateParser
  attr_accessor :html
  attr_accessor :test_value

  class Base
    def initialize(html)
      @html = html
      @test_value = "foo"
    end

    def parse!
      @html.css('a').each do |node|
        ::TemplateParser::Tag:ATag.substitute! node
      end
    end
  end
end

# template_parser/tag/a_tag.rb
module TemplateParser
  module Tag
    class ATag
      def self.substitute!(node)
        # I want to access +test_value+ from +TemplateParser+
        node = @test_value # => nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit based on Phrogz' comment**
I am currently thinking about something like:

```
p = TemplateParser.new(html, *args) # or TemplateParser::Base.new(html, *args)
p.append_css(file_or_string)
parsed_html = p.parse!
```

There shouldn't be much exposed methods because the parser should solve a non-general problem and is not portable. At least not at this early stage. What I've tried is to peek a bit from Nokogiri about the structure.

Comment: In addition to showing what you have (which is great) it would be even better if you showed what you think the user-facing code should look like. What methods and classes would you like to expose (and why)?

Comment: Added my thinkings about the user-facing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example code you've given, I'd recommend using composition to pass in an instance of `TemplateParser::Base` to the `parse!` method like so:

```
# in TemplateParser::Base#parse!
::TemplateParser::Tag::ATag.substitute! node, self

# TemplateParser::Tag::ATag
def self.substitute!(node, obj)
  node = obj.test_value
end
```

You will also need to move the `attr_accessor` calls into the `Base` class for this to work.

```
module TemplateParser
  class Base
    attr_accessor :html
    attr_accessor :test_value
    # ...
  end
end
```

Any other way I can think of right now of accessing `test_value` will be fairly convoluted considering the fact that `parse!` is a class method trying to access a different class instance's attribute.

The above assumes `@test_value` needs to be unique per `TemplateParser::Base` instance. If that's not the case, you could simplify the process by using a class or module instance variable.

```
module TemplateParser
  class Base
    @test_value = "foo"
    class << self
      attr_accessor :test_value
    end
    # ...
  end
end

# OR

module TemplateParser
  @test_value = "foo"
  class << self
    attr_accessor :test_value
  end
  class Base
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then set or retrieve the value with `TemplateParser::Base.test_value` OR `TemplateParser.test_value` depending on implementation.

Also, to perhaps state the obvious, I'm assuming your pseudo-code you've included here doesn't accurately reflect your real application code. If it does, then the `substitute!` method is a very round about way to achieve simple assignment. Just use `node = test_value` inside `TemplateParser::Base#parse!` and skip the round trip. I'm sure you know this, but it seemed worth mentioning at least...

Comment: many thanks for your detailed example and exclamation. The code I submitted is actually the same that I wanted to get up and running, so not really a pseudo thing.